# Handling different versions of code for beginners?

Tags: eclipse, version-control

While I make some (java) code, i feel the need to experiment and change some parts of it often.
I want these changes to appear in a copy of my existing project and not the original - something like "save as" vs "save".

I have some options to do this job(below). Problem is that I can't decide which one to choose.
As a beginner to version control, I want something that is very easy, but is also used in many software companies. I already have a lot of problems with compiler and run-time errors. I hope that a version control software will not make the coding process even more difficult.

Options-

```
1- Make copies of my code and label them with different numbers/dates.
2- Use SVN ?
3- Use GIT ?
```

Besides this, are there any other version control methods ?

EDIT-

Is is possible to do SVN inside eclipse itself or maybe integrate eclipse with some SVN software ? If yes, would this be a good approach ?

Comment: Use git. a) very useful tool to learn. b) does not require any server-side setup.

Comment: Or use svn a) very useful tool to learn b) does not require any server-side setup :) "Make copies of my code" is definitely not an option anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I currently use SVN for personal projects and Git for group projects. The way Git handles branching is pretty slick. SVN is just really easy to set up and use (you just need a URL as opposed to a ssh login on the client side).

If you're using Windows, I'd suggest using the TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit.

https://tortoisegit.org/

http://tortoisesvn.net/

I'd also suggest not going with the first option. Revision control is pretty important, even if you're just a hobbyist.

Comment: Can you give me some more reasons why I should favor SVN over the GIT for personal projects ?

Comment: Git is build to have everything decentralized, to the point where you don't even have to upload to a server in order to have it do revision control. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559590/collaborate-using-git-without-remote-server

Comment: I use SVN now mainly because it's what I have setup and it works well enough, not because it is better. I thought about this today and decided that you could also use Filezilla for a much less robust, but easier to setup, revision control.